# When String Contains Elements From Arrays In Order

Tags: arrays, node.js, if-statement, include, var

How do you make the console print true when the variable "message" contains an element from each array in order: "greetings" then "colour" then "names", but any words before "greetings" and after "colour" still prints true.

If the elements are out of order it should print false.

If there are words in-between the elements it should print false.

Check examples below current code.

Current Code:

```
var message = '';
var greetings = 'hi' || 'hello' || 'hey';
var colour = 'red' || 'green' || 'blue';
var names = 'john' || 'evan' || 'etienne';

if (message.includes(greetings + ' ' + colour + ' ' + names)) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

Examples of what it should print when message:

```
message = 'hi green evan' //true
message = 'lol hey blue john' //true
message = 'hello green etienne! xD' //true
message = 'evan green hi' //false because wrong element order
message = 'hi very green evan' //false because word in-between elements
```

Comment: How about convert those greetings, colours, and names to arrays? You can check index of one in the string, if its index is 0, truncate them from string, and continue with the rest

Comment: Do you know how to do that by passing the examples as well? I would appreciate it if you could answer

Comment: I have written a simple one using regex without using loop and truncating, it should shorten the evaluation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex for this.

```js
var message = "hello green etienne! xD";
var greetings = ["hi", "hello", "hey"].join("|");
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"].join("|");
var names = ["john", "evan",  "etienne"].join("|");
var reg = new RegExp("^.*(" + greetings + ")\\s+.*(" + colors + ")\\s+(" + names + ").*$");
console.log(reg.test(message));
```

Comment: Thank you Jun Back it passes all examples!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var message = 'hi green evan';
var greetings = ["hi","hello","hey"];
var colour = ['red','green','blue'];
var names = ['john','evan','etienne'];
var contained = false;
greetings.some(x =>{
   colour.some(z=>{
     names.some(e=>{
        if(message.includes(x + ' ' + z + ' ' + e)){
         contained = true;
     alert(true);
        }
      });
    });
});

if(!contained)
 alert(false);
```

You could do it like this. Probably not the best way to do it but the first thing that came to my mind

Comment: Thanks Garret for answering! It works and I would up vote it if I had 15 reputation. I have to accept Jun Bach's answer though because I think it's more efficient, but thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Np, just was giving an answer as no one else had